# getBooleanExtra cannot be applied to a Boolean variable

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to pass booleans between activities:

**MainActivity**

```
boolean stream = false;
boolean wifi = false;

public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
    if (((ToggleButton)view).isChecked()) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentHour());
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentMinute());

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);

        myIntent.putExtra("snooze",false);
        myIntent.putExtra("stream",stream);
        myIntent.putExtra("wifi",wifi);

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

And then retrieving it in my broadcastreceiver:

**AlarmReceiver**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        Boolean wifi = intent.getBooleanExtra("wifi");
        Boolean stream = intent.getBooleanExtra("stream");
        Boolean snooze = intent.getBooleanExtra("snooze");
        //.....
```

For each getBooleanExtra I get the error:

```
error: method getBooleanExtra in class Intent cannot be applied to given types;
required: String,boolean
found: boolean
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

If I change Boolean to boolean, the error changes to *found: String* instead of *found: boolean*

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[getBooleanExtra](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) return a `primitive boolean` type  and you have to give a default value

```
Boolean stream = intent.getBooleanExtra("stream",false);
// ^^ wrapper class                              ^^^ default value
```

or better you can use `boolean` to avoid unnecessary `autoboxing` from `boolean` to `Boolean`.

```
    boolean wifi = intent.getBooleanExtra("wifi",false);
    boolean stream = intent.getBooleanExtra("stream",false);
    boolean snooze = intent.getBooleanExtra("snooze",false);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, stupid question. Guess I'll be getting banned from asking again

Comment: @JenniferCanas i am glad that i could help , always check the docs in case of these kind of errors , happy coding